# Can one imagine spaces where point reflections are not bijective?

Tags: symmetry

Not a mathematician, and the question probably does not make sense but asking it anyway:

In usual euclidian spaces, central inversion through O(0,...,0) of point M(x1,...,xN) gives you one and only one point M'(-x1,...,-xN). I would write this
$$I_O(M)=M'$$
Do you know of any bizarre space where this wouldn't be the case ? Where :
$$I_O(M)=M' \text{or } M''$$

Comment: if we want the reflection to be inverse to itself ($I_O \circ I_O = \operatorname{id}$) then it would certainly need to be bijective... the question would be what the precise meaning of "reflection" in "bizarre" spaces  should be...

Comment: Maybe something like : there exist some integer $k$ such as $I_O^k=Id$, without $I_O$ being a rotation, I actually don't know what really characterizes point symmetries except for the condition you mentionned